# Filetype for client-editable site settings?

Tags: xml, content-management-system, frameworks

Currently the php framework I'm dealing with has a simple conf file with `define`'s in it. The update I need to make is basically have simple client settings editable for the application which uses the framework. ( And there is a custom made CMS that is programmed to support this framework )

The framework doesn't rely on a database to store any settings nor content, its purely flat file based.

I'm trying to decide on a file type for the client editable settings file, which will contain simple non-confidential information that is public, such as:

- site name
- logo
- address information
- google id

I was thinking of just storing this as `XML`, in a format such as:

```
<settings>
    <setting name="site_name">Name of Site</setting>
    <setting name="google_id">1248498</setting>
    <setting name="logo" type="image"><![CDATA[ <img src="foo.gif"> ]]></setting>
</settings>
```

I'm still a bit confused on whether this is a decent file type, it seems like it's fine for most settings but the tricky part is I'll need to make the logo editable where it will be an `img` element, so I just wrapped it in `CDATA` section and gave it a custom attribute.

With this hopefully I'll just make a module within the CMS to edit this type of file. Looking for any tips anyone may have - and to reiterate I can't use a database, nor will I store important information such as passwords.. just basic public settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format is fine, if you use a library to read and write the xml file, '<' and '>' should be automatically escaped for you.